# Generating html to an array of objects - different property to every other position

Tags: javascript

I am working on a leaderboard that is generated from an array of objects. I sort it by the number of votes and it works fine. The only thing I can't figure out is how to create a different background to every other position (by adding a class where necessary).

I am able to filter every other position:
`const filtration = positionOfPlayers.filter((_, index) => index % 2 != 0);`

Still no idea how to use that filtration to add a class so it is not in my code anymore.

I also tried CSS :nth-child(even) on a .js-container the leaderboard lives in, but I found out that what is generated by JS is treated as one thing.

```
.js-container:nth-child(even){
  background: rgba(226, 236, 226, 0.7);
}
```

With **even** everything gets the background, with **odd** nothing gets the background.

This is my starting point, where html is generated the same for each player.
I played around with if statements, nothing seems to work as expected.

```
function renderHTML() {
  let playersHTML = '';
 
  positionOfPlayers.forEach((player) => {  
      playersHTML+= `
        <div class="table__line grid">
          <p class="img"><img src="${player.image}"></p>
          <p class="text">${player.name}</p>
          <p class="text col"><span>${player.votes.count}</span><button id="${player.id}" class="vote-btn">vote now</button><span class="small">${player.votes.recommendation}</span></p>
          <p class="text">${player.earnings}</p>
        </div>`;
      })
      document.querySelector('.js-container').innerHTML = playersHTML;
      
  }
```

[image: The design made without JS.]
This pic shows what I am going for visually.
When I made it without JS html for each player would look like this, only the next line would have class="two", and so on - and I could add whatever I wanted in CSS:

```
<div class="table__line one grid">
 <p class="img"><img src="img/player1.jpg"></p>
 <p class="text">PAUL J. VANAUKEN</p>
 <p class="text col"><span id="js-nr1">22.343</span><button id="vote-btn" class="vote-btn">vote now</button><span class="small">18.220 recommandations</span></p>
  <p class="text">$54.000</p>
</div>
```

[image: The design with JS]

This is what I get with

```
.js-container:nth-child(even){
  background: rgba(226, 236, 226, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need to add a class. You've used [`nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/) selector, but not showed a [mcve] of it.

Comment: How does `const filtration = positionOfPlayers.filter...` fit in to the code you've shown in the question? What is the desired outcome? A more complete example is definitely needed here.

Comment: You need `.js-container .grid:nth-child(even){..}`

Comment: Oh my, it was that simple... Thanks.